# is this possible to print the web page in android without popup?

Tags: printing, android-print-framework

> I am using default android printer option (android version 4.4)
>
> I want to byPass printManager adapter popup. how to hide the popup and give a direct print to the printer in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot extend PrintManager class. It is a final class .Please check below link

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/print/PrintManager.java

These guys have designed their own printing framework.Where they are designing their own dialog.Have a look

http://apf.isb-vietnam.com/index.php/programming-with-apf.html

Comment: Please combine your answers into one, and remove the other one!

Comment: This link is dead: http://apf.isb-vietnam.com/index.php/programming-with-apf.html

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me like the answer is **yes**.

Here is the `print()` method from Android's `PrintManager` class:

```
public PrintJob print(String printJobName, PrintDocumentAdapter documentAdapter, PrintAttributes attributes)
{
    if (mService == null)
    {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Feature android.software.print not available");
        return null;
    }
    if (!(mContext instanceof Activity))
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can print only from an activity");
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(printJobName))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("printJobName cannot be empty");
    }
    if (documentAdapter == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("documentAdapter cannot be null");
    }
    PrintDocumentAdapterDelegate delegate = new PrintDocumentAdapterDelegate((Activity) mContext, documentAdapter);
    try
    {
        Bundle result = mService.print(printJobName, delegate, attributes, mContext.getPackageName(), mAppId, mUserId);
        if (result != null)
        {
            PrintJobInfo printJob = result.getParcelable(EXTRA_PRINT_JOB);
            IntentSender intent = result.getParcelable(EXTRA_PRINT_DIALOG_INTENT);
            if (printJob == null || intent == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            try
            {
                mContext.startIntentSender(intent, null, 0, 0, 0);
                return new PrintJob(printJob, this);
            }
            catch (SendIntentException sie)
            {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Couldn't start print job config activity.", sie);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (RemoteException re)
    {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error creating a print job", re);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Simply create your own class (I will pretend it is named `MyPrintManager`) which `extends PrintManager` and `@Override` the `print()` method in it. Then, use the code above, but remove this line:

```
mContext.startIntentSender(intent, null, 0, 0, 0);
```

Then, get an instance of the `MyPrintManager` class using the code below:

```
MyPrintManager printManager = (MyPrintManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
```

You could try this, though I am not sure if it works, because I haven't tested it. Please reply with the result, and I will try to help you further if it didn't work.

Comment: what is mService in this above method??

Comment: @John Take a look at the `PrintManager` class from The Android source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/afd1967/core/java/android/print/PrintManager.java It's an `IPrintManager` which is supplied by the system during creation. I think you can copy the whole `PrintManager` class, but change the `print()` method.

Comment: I tried copying the PrintManager class But there is no use IPrintManager class not found and some import classes are missing 

like : import com.android.internal.os.SomeArgs;

import libcore.io.IoUtils;

import android.printservice.PrintServiceInfo;

and if i try to copy any file from GrepCode. its continuously asking so many class files . 

so is there any other way to over come this problem??

Comment: @John Sadly I don't know any other way. I'm not even sure this will work. Sorry.

Comment: @John No problems! ;)

Comment: can't extends **PrintManager**