# How to print multiple items using the same PrintAttributes

Tags: android, google-cloud-print, android-print-framework

First off is the more general problem that I want to solve and then I'll get into the current approach that I am seeking help for.

During report generation I want to create and print many pdf pages.  In order to optimize the user experience I want to create and print the pdfs in the background once the user has selected the Print Attributes since the layout and printer will be the same for all pdfs.  I believe that I need to create and print the pdfs one at a time since on some phones google cloud print does not support documents that have 8 pages (there is a consistent error, for example on the Galaxy S5 using a pdf document that is maybe 150mb).
There are other issues with creating very large pdfs and it will be common to have over 100 pages generated so creating one large pdf and sending it to the printer will likely not work considering hardware constraints.

The specific question is how can I reuse the PrintAttribute without showing the dialog each time.  [It seems like it might not currently be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738148/is-this-possible-to-print-the-web-page-in-android-without-popup) so I am open to other solutions.